# console.log not a function when passed as an argument to some other function and called within

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm attempting to build my own for loop construct.

```
function loop(value, test, update, body) {
    if (test(value)) {
        body(value);
        return loop(update(value), test, update);
    }
}
```

The error the Edge browser is giving me:

```
VM1297:3 Uncaught TypeError: body is not a function
    at loop (<anonymous>:3:3)
    at loop (<anonymous>:4:10)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Using this call:

```
loop(10, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log)
```

Why does JS not see body as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not passing body as last parameter in next iteration.
You should do `loop(update(value), test, update, body);` instead of `loop(update(value), test, update);`

```js
function loop(value, test, update, body) {
  if (test(value)) {
    body(value);
    return loop(update(value), test, update, body);
  }
}

loop(10, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log)
```

Comment: I did not notice, much appreciated

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. :) thanks.